# How to do a connect request for the Facebook App in localhost

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-apps

I'm creating a login with facebook authentication for my application which is currently in locahost. I created an app in facebook.

Now when I try to access this URL: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=my_app_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/`

I'm getting this error:

`Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

Then I tried to add the `localhost`to my app settings `App Domains` and I'm getting another error there and cannot save it:

`This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: localhost`

Am I doing it wrong? or what is the right way to do it for the localhost?

Comment: Well, does any of the URLs mentioned in the message start with http(s)://localhost …?

Comment: I tried something like : `https://locahost` and still getting the same error.

Comment: _Where_ did you try to input that value?

Comment: In the `App Domains` field

Comment: `https://localhost` is not a valid _domain_, it’s an URL (and as such does not belong into that field). Only the `localhost` is the _domain name_ here – and as the message already said, it has to _match_ the URL you input into one of the _other_ fields mentioned.

Comment: I tried with `localhost`, `http://localhost`, http://localhost:8080` (though it's not domain) and every time I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you add a “Platform” already in your app settings? If not, add platform “Website”, and input `http://localhost/` as Site URL. After that, you should be able to add `localhost` as app domain.

Comment: Alright.. it worked. If you make it as an answer, I can mark it as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a “Platform” first in app settings.

Add platform “Website”, and input `http://localhost/` as Site URL. Only after that will you be able to call the login dialog from your localhost website.